# How to make core data of Ios has the ability to read sqlite which is generated from other platform?

Tags: ios, ruby, core-data, sqlite

I generate some sqlite database which using Ruby or Php, and I want to use them both for my Ios Apps and Android Apps.However,everything for Android got fine,but not Ios.
The App of Ios would crash.So I wonder if there is someway to make the core data can read the sqlite database which generate from other platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only workaround is..

Generage an sqlite database file using core data. Dump the data into this file manually and keep it in the app bundle. Once the application launch first time, replace the existing sqlite database file in the documents folder with the one in the bundle. Automatically the core data will use populated sqlite database.

Follow the steps:

1. Create a core data sample project using Xcode. Add the data model file and create the entities.
2. Run the project. Coredata will create empty sqlite file in the documents folder.
3. Take the sqlite file and manually populate the tables using what ever easy way you have.
4. Add the populated sqlite file to the app bundle. You can't edit this file at runtime so you have to place the same in the documents folder at first launch (replace the existing file).
5. Coredata will take your sqlite file hence forth. So that you can also edit the sqlite file.

Comment: Thank you.But if the size of sqlite is big,it will take such a long time to make the core data generate.And I also want to use this for update the data of app without restart the app